# WordPress pre_get_posts Hook: 404 Error Issue on Custom Page in WooCommerce Function within functions.php File

Tags: hook-woocommerce

Introduction to the Problem:
I'm facing an issue with my pre_get_posts function in WordPress, located in my child theme's functions.php file. When adding the condition `(is_shop() || is_page('cosa-vedere-a-brescia'))`, I receive a 404 error on the custom page 'cosa-vedere-a-brescia,' while the shop page works correctly. What could be the causes? Below, I provide additional details if needed.

I have created the `custom_pre_get_posts` function, working correctly on the Shop page of my website (https://bresciaeventi.com/). The function checks if the main query is on the WooCommerce shop page in the frontend. If satisfied, it sets a search condition for the ACF "leonessa" field with specific values (gold, silver, bronze) and orders the results accordingly.

The correct if statement in the function is as follows:

if ($query->is_main_query() && is_shop() && !is_admin()) {

However, extending the if statement with `(is_shop() || is_page('cosa-vedere-a-brescia'))` results in a 404 error on the 'cosa-vedere-a-brescia' page, while the shop page works correctly.

The problematic if statement is:

if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && (is_shop() || is_page('cosa-vedere-a-brescia'))) {

What could be the causes of this issue, and how can it be resolved?

function custom_pre_get_posts($query) {
// Verifica se la query è principale e se ci troviamo nel frontend (non nel backend)

```
if ($query->is_main_query() && is_shop() && !is_admin()) {


//   if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && (is_shop() || is_page('cosa-vedere-a-brescia'))) {
     
    // Condizioni comuni per entrambe le pagine
    $values = array('oro', 'argento', 'bronzo');

    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
    );

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'leonessa', // Sostituisci con il nome esatto del tuo campo ACF
            'value' => $value,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    $query->set('orderby', array('meta_value' => $values, 'meta_type' => 'CHAR'));
}
```

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts', 100, 1);

I carefully examined the condition `(is_shop() || is_page('cosa-vedere-a-brescia'))`. I attempted to run the function by deactivating plugins that could interfere with the site, and I haven't activated anything that affects permalinks. Now, I plan to explore alternative condition options or filtering strategies tailored to my specific needs.